# Delegate call interrupting click event

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have a problem in a complex bit of code. It appears that a delegate method call is interrupting the click event of a dynamically added button. I haven't coded up a basic example to be 100% sure but it looks like that's what's happening.

We have a .aspx page which contains a user control

```
<wachter:ViewEditTemplateControl ID="veSiteInfo" runat="server" Mode="View" EnableAjax="false" CanEditPermission="SiteInfoCanEdit">
                                <ViewButtonsTemplate>
                                 <asp:ImageButton ID="ibMap" CommandName="Map" ImageUrl="../Images/NavIcons/map.png" Visible="true" ToolTip="Site Map" runat="server" />
                                 <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnSiteNotes" CommandName="SiteNotes"  ImageUrl="/Images/iconInfo.png" visible="false" ToolTip="Site Notes" runat="server"  />
                                 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdit" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/iconEdit.png" />
                                </ViewButtonsTemplate>
                                <ViewTemplate>
                                    <uc1:SiteInformationView ID="SiteInformationView1" runat="server" />
                                </ViewTemplate>
                                <EditTemplate>
                                    <uc1:SiteInformationEdit ID="SiteInformationEdit1" runat="server" />
                                </EditTemplate>
                            </wachter:ViewEditTemplateControl>
```

In the .aspx's codebehind we set a delegate to the ViewTemplate's usercontrol

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        (veSiteInfo.FindControl("SiteInformationView1") as JobSiteViewControl).SiteChanged += SiteChanged;
    }
```

This delegate is used to set the visibility of our edit button imgEdit.

The ViewEditTemplateControl contains a bit of code in the codebehind which dymaically adds save/edit buttons

```
Button btnSave = new Button();
            btnSave.ID = "btnSave";
            btnSave.Text = "Save";
            btnSave.CommandName = "Save";

            root.Controls.Add(btnSave);

            Button btnCancel = new Button();
            btnCancel.ID = "btnCancel";
            btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";
            btnCancel.CommandName = "Cancel";
            btnCancel.CausesValidation = false;

            root.Controls.Add(btnCancel);
```

In the ViewTemplate's codebehind we call this delegate on page init.

```
public Action<JobSiteEntity> SiteChanged;

public override void InitControl() 
{

    if (SiteChanged != null)
            SiteChanged(DataItemTyped); 
}
```

The problem is that clicking the dynamically added btnCancel triggers the delegate but doesn't fire the event handler for it.

If I comment out setting the delegate, the button's event handler gets hit.

I know my code snippets aren't the best but any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution, but I've ended up removing the delegate call and directly accessing a method on the base page.

```
if (Page is IJobEntityPage)
        {
            ((IJobEntityPage)Page).SetEditVisibility(DataItemTyped);
        }
```